# Ordered generic Map implementation?

Tags: java, collections, guava, linkedhashmap, apache-commons-collection

Which library is the best with ordered map implementation?

Implementation is required to be

1) generic

2) accessible by integer index

One from JRE can't be accessed by index: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

One from Commons-Collections 3.2 is not generic: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LinkedMap.html

One from Commons-Collection 4.0 is not released yet.

And can't find appropriate class in Guava. Is there one?

Comment: ordered as in insertion order? natural order? custom order?

Comment: Do you realize that any linked map will give you O(N) performance for retrieval by index? You can get identical performance by simply walking the iterator.

Comment: If you describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve, you might find that there's a better solution.

Comment: @parsifal I disagree with O(N). Isn't it possible to have two parallel structures in implementation?

Comment: @Suzan - so what data structure do you propose?

Comment: It's fine to disagree, but at least you should understand the data structures. If you want list semantics, you have two options: linked or array-backed. A linked list always costs O(N) for indexed retrieval; there's no way around that. An array-backed list gives you O(1) indexed retrieval, but if you delete items from the map you'll need to pay O(N) to update the array.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with [`ImmutableSortedMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap.html) (it's immutable and null hostile):

```
// use ImmutableSortedMap#copyOf or one of builders - naturalOrder or orderedBy
ImmutableSortedMap<K, V> map = ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(origMap, comparator);
map.keySet().asList().get(index);
```

But what problem are you trying to solve? Seems to me like bad code smell...

**EDIT:**

If you want insertion order instead of using comparator, just use [`ImmutableMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
ImmutableMap.copyOf(origMap).keySet().asList().get(index);
```